# WakeLock in Google cloud messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, wakelock

I am learning GCM through the following tutorial, [Android Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html). There is such line "*your application must acquire a wake lock before starting the service—otherwise the device could be put to sleep before the service is started.*"
In the example codes, first the receiver receive messages and then trigger your own implementation of `IntentService`, the codes are as follow.

My question is why we obtain this `WakeLock` in `IntentService` class but not in the `Receiver` class?

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public final void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        MyIntentService.runIntentInService(context, intent);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
    }
}




public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static PowerManager.WakeLock sWakeLock;
    private static final Object LOCK = MyIntentService.class;

    static void runIntentInService(Context context, Intent intent) {
        synchronized(LOCK) {
            if (sWakeLock == null) {
                PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                sWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "my_wakelock");
            }
        }
        sWakeLock.acquire();
        intent.setClassName(context, MyIntentService.class.getName());
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public final void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {
                handleRegistration(intent);
            } else if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) {
                handleMessage(intent);
            }
        } finally {
            synchronized(LOCK) {
                sWakeLock.release();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wakelock is for the Service. When you are done with wakelock object, you have to release the object, that's why.